# Issue installing *gfortran*

Tags: gcc, tar, fortran

I am trying to installing gfortran on my ubuntu system and I am following the steps mentioned in http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries32Linux , unfortunately one of the step in the installation steps to says

Install using the following command:

tar -xzvf gfortran-4.5-linux-i686.tar.gz -C /

but the download link provides a .deb file which I have installed it. Now when I check for gfortran, it says not installed. Any clue? how should I follow the further?

Steps I have completed are:
1) Installed  libraries: GMP Library, MPFR Library, and MPC Library.
2)Downloaded the gfortran-4.6 Debian and installed using the cmd. sudo dpkg -i .deb

anything else I need to do? do I need to create any path or symbolic link? please help,thanks! Please Note: I have no internet access and cannot use software center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not install the package?

```
sudo apt-get install gfortran
```

Comment: I have tried it and you can see my edited question for what I have been doing. any further suggestions. I guess I need to give a path for installing.

Answer (score 0):

If you just download the **.deb** file, and open (with Software Centre), this may resolve your problem.

*A 'Debian' file (.deb) is the default install method for Debian and Ubuntu variants of Linux.*

---

**UPDATE**

I followed the link you gave.

The file **[gcc-4.8-infrastructure-32bit.tar.xz](http://gfortran.com/download/i686/gcc-4.8-infrastructure-32bit.tar.xz)** is a closer match the instructions you were using.

I also read **[ReadMe-32bit](http://gfortran.com/download/i686/PLEASE_README-32bit.txt)**, which has (possibly) even simpler instructions.

*Presumably you can't just use 4.6.3, which is ready to install (for **12.04**) in the Ubuntu repositories.*

Comment: I have been installing the dependencies for a big list and was successfully able to install it. Thanks for your comment.